# I am using Razor page layout in mvc index view but I won't able to call Razor pagemodel

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I am getting error in layout page because layout page using pagemodel which is very important for layout.

Here is the code:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            testmodel objPage = new testmodel();
            return View();
            // return new RedirectToPageResult("/Page");
        }
```

Here is the view:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> using Razor page layout in mvc index view but I won't able to call
> Razor pagemodel

I guess you have a Razor Pages project, and want to use the razor layout in the Index view? Below is a demo, you can refer to it.

ViewModelBase:

```
 public class ViewModelBase
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; } = "ff";
    }
```

SomeViewModel:

```
public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@model Models.ViewModelBase
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   @Model.LastName
  ...
```

Index action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {            
            var model = new SomeViewModel()
          {
            Name="dd"
          };
        return View(model);          
        }
```

Index view:

```
@model yourprojectName.Models.SomeViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Model.Name
```

In Program.cs (asp.net core 6), change your code like below :

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
...
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

result:

[image]

Comment: but I don't want to create new layout I have to use razorpage layout which is create in page folder

Comment: @RaniThakur Yes, this  is using  razorpage layout which is create in page folder. Not a new layout.

Comment: i try this but my pagemodel is not called and i am using pagemodel data in layout page

Comment: @RaniThakur Could you share your code of  layout page ?

Comment: i cant share full code but i will give hint

Comment: @model test.Models.PageModel this model i am using in layout